# Tkinter and waiting

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a mp3 player using python 3 and Tkinter, using pygame.mixer for the MP3s.  When you input a directory and press play it auto finds all the MP3s in the directory (using glob) and adds them to a list.  I use a for loop to load then play the music, but when it plays it starts the next song immediately and automatically repeats till the end of the list where it plays only that song.  I tried using time.sleep() which works but freezes the program.  How can I wait till the song is over to start the next one and not freeze the program.

My current code (just the function to play the music):

```
def play():
    print("playing")
    global playing
    playing = True
    direct = directorye.get()
    direct = direct.lower()

    if direct.endswith(".mp3"):
        mixer.music.load(directorye.get())
        mixer.music.play()
    else:
        dire = r"C:\Users\agweb\Downloads\Music"  #for the time being I just hard coded the directory
        mp3s = glob.glob(dire + r"\*.MP3") # adds all MP3s in directory to list
        #mp3s =+ glob.glob(directorye.get() + "*.MP3")
        for i in mp3s:
            print(i)

            mixer.music.load(i)
            mixer.music.play()
            audio = MP3(i)
            time.sleep(audio.info.length) #works but freezes program
```

Comment: check `mixer` documentation if it doesn't generate event when it ends song - and you could use pygame's event loop to get it. Or maybe it can run some function when it ends song.

Comment: see [pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) - it can generate event when it ends playing song, and you would need `root.after(millisecond , check_events)` to check periodically pygame's events.

Comment: @stovfl no! he should try to register for an event the player emits to tell that the song is over! when he gets that event, he pauses the player, set the next song and put the player in "playing" state and so...till all the song got played

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches possible.

Since `tkinter` is thread-safeish(*) on Python 3, probably the easiest way is to start a slightly modified version of your `play` function as a second thread.

In the global context, create a `threading.Event`. I would suggest the name `stop_playing`.

In the play function, only sleep for a little interval at a time, checking if `stop_playing` is set:

```
for i in mp3s:
    mixer.music.load(i)
    mixer.music.play()
    audio = MP3(i)
    playtime = 0
    interval = 100  # ms
    while playtime < audio.info.length:
        time.sleep(interval)
        playtime += interval
        if stop_playing.is_set():
            # TODO: stop the current playback.
            # Then exit the thread.
            return
```

The new callback for the "Play" button should create a thread for `play()` and `start()` it.

The callback for the "Stop" button should simply call `stop_playing.set()`. That will cause the playing thread to stop.

(* Provided it uses a `tcl` compiled with threading enabled.)

Comment: problem is `pygame.mixer.music.queue` can keep only one file in queue - and you don't know if you have to add next file or not.

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank for the answer,  I don't entirely understand.

Comment: @AndrewWebberley In a second thread, you *can* use `time.sleep()` without freezing the program.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work you can test it

```
from threading import Thread
import pygame
from itertools import cycle


def put_next_music_inside(loop_on_musics, stop_event):
    for cur_music in loop_on_musics:
        while pygame.mixer.music.peek(stop_event):
            pass 
        pygame.event.get(stop_event)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(cur_music)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()


pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.init()

END_OF_MUSIC_EVENT = -100
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(END_OF_MUSIC_EVENT)
list_of_music = []#fill it with musics'path
first_music = list_of_music[0]
del list_of_music[0]
list_of_music.append(first_music)
loop_on_musics = cycle(list_of_music)
t = Thread(target=put_next_music_inside, args=(loop_on_musics, END_OF_MUSIC_EVENT))
t.start()
pygame.mixer.music.load(first_music)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```